# offset position off objects along spline animations nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor

how to offset position off objects along spline&[image]

Comment: Hi, could you add another screenshot or a sketch of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Did You try to offset an object from its origin in edit mode?